# Devise not responding correctly to JSON message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, devise

I am finding trouble in having Devise responding correctly to a JSON message.

the following is working fine

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:5000/users/sign_in.json' -d 'user[email]=MYUSER' -d 'user[password]=MYPASSWORD'
```

> Completed 201 Created in 171ms

In place, I would like to have a more proper JSON format

```
curl -v -b cookie.file -c cookie.file -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"user":{"mail":"MYUSER","password":"MYPASSWORD"}}' http://localhost:5000/users/sign_in.json
```

But I does not seem to work

> Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as JSON
>   23:10:32 web.1     |   Parameters: {"user"=>{"mail"=>"MYUSER", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "session"=>{"user"=>{"mail"=>"MYUSER", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"devise/sessions", "format"=>"json"}}
>   23:10:32 web.1     | Completed 401 Unauthorized in 11ms

Any ideas?
thanks

Comment: It's balking at a security concern. CSRF stands for cross-site request forgery. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Comment: that warning is common to both case (in the successful as well I have "WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity", this is coming from protect_from_forgery), but might be a confusing point, I will edit the post. thanks.

Comment: What makes you think the 2nd version is not working then? I don't see any other warnings or error messages.

Comment: the 401 Unauthorized. And the JSON results should contains the authentication token (that is the way I setup the rails controller), but in the second case is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
curl -v -b cookie.file -c cookie.file -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"user" : {"email":"MYUSER" , "password":"MYPASSWORD" }}' http://localhost:5000/users/sign_in.json
```

It is doing the job. It turn out to be a (plain) misspelling (mail in place of the correct email). Rails logs did not help me to find the solution quickly